# Kаждый элемент массива json в отдельный div

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

Здравствуйте,

Подскажите, я хочу отобразить данные json массива через html в `<ol>` листе, отобразить получается, но задача в том чтобы каждый элемент массива отображался в отдельном div боксе. У меня в div попадают сразу все элементы, как это исправить?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX JSON CAR SALES</title>
    <style>
    #logo{
    display:block;
    height:25em;
    width:27em;
    margin:auto;
    }
    #empData{
    border:2px solid black;
    }
    #empData img{
    height:15em;
    width:22em;
    }
    .cars{
    border:2px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    }   
    ol{
    margin-left:5em;
    }

    </style>
    <script>
        function getCars(){
            var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                    //the request is completed, now check its status
                    if(ajaxRequest.status == 200){
                        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);
                        console.log(jsonObj)

                        var carsArray = jsonObj.carsList;


                        var tabData = "<div class='cars'><ol>";
                        for(var i = 0;i < carsArray.length; i++){
                        tabData = tabData +("<li>" + 
                        carsArray[i].Make + 
                        "</li><li>" + 
                        carsArray[i].Model+ 
                        "</li><li>" + 
                        carsArray[i].Fuel_Type + 
                        "</li><li>" + 
                        carsArray[i].Color+
                        "</li><li>" + 
                        carsArray[i].Price+
                        "</li><li>" + 
                        "<img src='"+carsArray[i].pic+"' alt='Car'>"+
                        "</li>");

                        }
                        tabData = tabData + "</ol></div>";

                        document.getElementById("empData").innerHTML =tabData;




                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("Status error: " + ajaxRequest.status);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Ignored readyState: " + ajaxRequest.readyState);
                }
            }
            ajaxRequest.open('GET', 'cars.json');
            ajaxRequest.send();
        }

    </script>   
</head>
<body onload="getCars()">
    <img src="images/logo.jpg" id="logo" alt="Logo">
    <div id="empData">  

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот сам массив:

```
{"carsList": [
    {"Make":"Toyota","Model":"Corolla","Year":"2015","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"White","Price":"€30000","pic":"images/toyota.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Ford","Model":"Fiesta","Year":"2005","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"Red","Price":"€5000","pic":"images/ford.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Nissan","Model":"Qashqai","Year":"2017","Fuel_Type":"Diesel","Color":"Silver","Price":"€45000","pic":"images/nissan.jpg"},
    {"Make":"BMW","Model":"5 series","Year":"2012","Fuel_Type":"Diesel","Color":"Silver","Price":"€40000","pic":"images/bmw.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Mazda","Model":"3","Year":"2002","Fuel_Type":"Diesel","Color":"Grey","Price":"€3000","pic":"images/mazda.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Mercedes","Model":"E200","Year":"2009","Fuel_Type":"Diesel","Color":"Light Grey","Price":"€18000","pic":"images/mercedes.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Volkswagen","Model":"Passat","Year":"2005","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"Black","Price":"€4000","pic":"images/passat.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Audi","Model":"A6","Year":"2007","Fuel_Type":"Diesel","Color":"Black","Price":"€7000","pic":"images/audi.jpg"},
    {"Make":"KIA","Model":"Rio", "Year":"2017","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"Red","Price":"€48000","pic":"images/kia.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Hyundai","Model":"Santa Fe", "Year":"2006","Fuel_Type":"Diesel","Color":"Silver","Price":"€6800","pic":"images/hyundai.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Alfa Romeo","Model":"Giulietta", "Year":"2009","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"Red","Price":"€2500","pic":"images/alfa_romeo.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Bentley","Model":"Continental", "Year":"2014","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"White","Price":"€90000","pic":"images/bentley.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Cadillac","Model":"Seville", "Year":"1996","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"Black","Price":"€20000","pic":"images/cadillac.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Chevrolet","Model":"Camaro", "Year":"2010","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"Silver","Price":"€30000","pic":"images/chevrolet.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Chrysler","Model":"300 MY12", "Year":"2015","Fuel_Type":"Diesel","Color":"Black","Price":"€58000","pic":"images/chrysler.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Daewoo","Model":"Lanos", "Year":"2002","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"White","Price":"€1500","pic":"images/daewoo.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Fiat","Model":"Ducato", "Year":"2004","Fuel_Type":"Diesel","Color":"White","Price":"€1900","pic":"images/fiat.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Hummer","Model":"H3", "Year":"2007","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"Orange","Price":"€55000","pic":"images/hummer.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Skoda","Model":"Octavia", "Year":"2009","Fuel_Type":"Diesel","Color":"Red","Price":"€15000","pic":"images/skoda.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Dodge","Model":"Ram", "Year":"2011","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"Black","Price":"€38000","pic":"images/dodge.jpg"}
]}
```

Comment: Так в цикле после каждого LI поставьте <div>

Comment: мне надо чтобы информация о каждый машине была в разных div, у меня 20 машин, мне надо 20 div

Comment: Просто внутри цикла добавьте открытие `div` перед первым `li`, и закрытие `div` в конце цикла соответственно, что сложного-то?

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*
if(ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
*/
  let jsonObj = getTestJson(); //JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);
  let carsArray = jsonObj.carsList, 
      itemsHtml = '';
  carsArray.forEach(car => {
    itemsHtml += `\n
      <li><div>
        <h4>${car.Make} ${car.Model}</h4>
        Топливо: ${car.Fuel_Type}<br>
        Цвет: ${car.Color}<br>
        Стоимость: ${car.Price}
        <img arc="${car.pic}" alt="Car">
      </div></li>`; 
  }); 
  document.getElementById('empData').innerHTML = `<div class="cars"><ol>${itemsHtml}</ol></div>`;
/*
}
else
  console.log("Status error: " + ajaxRequest.status);
*/


function getTestJson() {
  return {"carsList": [
    {"Make":"Toyota","Model":"Corolla","Year":"2015","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"White","Price":"€30000","pic":"images/toyota.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Ford","Model":"Fiesta","Year":"2005","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"Red","Price":"€5000","pic":"images/ford.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Nissan","Model":"Qashqai","Year":"2017","Fuel_Type":"Diesel","Color":"Silver","Price":"€45000","pic":"images/nissan.jpg"},
    {"Make":"BMW","Model":"5 series","Year":"2012","Fuel_Type":"Diesel","Color":"Silver","Price":"€40000","pic":"images/bmw.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Mazda","Model":"3","Year":"2002","Fuel_Type":"Diesel","Color":"Grey","Price":"€3000","pic":"images/mazda.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Mercedes","Model":"E200","Year":"2009","Fuel_Type":"Diesel","Color":"Light Grey","Price":"€18000","pic":"images/mercedes.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Volkswagen","Model":"Passat","Year":"2005","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"Black","Price":"€4000","pic":"images/passat.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Audi","Model":"A6","Year":"2007","Fuel_Type":"Diesel","Color":"Black","Price":"€7000","pic":"images/audi.jpg"},
    {"Make":"KIA","Model":"Rio", "Year":"2017","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"Red","Price":"€48000","pic":"images/kia.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Hyundai","Model":"Santa Fe", "Year":"2006","Fuel_Type":"Diesel","Color":"Silver","Price":"€6800","pic":"images/hyundai.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Alfa Romeo","Model":"Giulietta", "Year":"2009","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"Red","Price":"€2500","pic":"images/alfa_romeo.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Bentley","Model":"Continental", "Year":"2014","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"White","Price":"€90000","pic":"images/bentley.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Cadillac","Model":"Seville", "Year":"1996","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"Black","Price":"€20000","pic":"images/cadillac.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Chevrolet","Model":"Camaro", "Year":"2010","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"Silver","Price":"€30000","pic":"images/chevrolet.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Chrysler","Model":"300 MY12", "Year":"2015","Fuel_Type":"Diesel","Color":"Black","Price":"€58000","pic":"images/chrysler.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Daewoo","Model":"Lanos", "Year":"2002","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"White","Price":"€1500","pic":"images/daewoo.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Fiat","Model":"Ducato", "Year":"2004","Fuel_Type":"Diesel","Color":"White","Price":"€1900","pic":"images/fiat.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Hummer","Model":"H3", "Year":"2007","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"Orange","Price":"€55000","pic":"images/hummer.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Skoda","Model":"Octavia", "Year":"2009","Fuel_Type":"Diesel","Color":"Red","Price":"€15000","pic":"images/skoda.jpg"},
    {"Make":"Dodge","Model":"Ram", "Year":"2011","Fuel_Type":"Petrol","Color":"Black","Price":"€38000","pic":"images/dodge.jpg"}
  ]}; 
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #777; 
  font: 16px Arial, sans-serif;
}

#empData {
  width: 27em; 
  margin: 30px auto; padding: 20px 10px; 
  background-color: #fff; 
}

#empData li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: ''; 
  display: block; 
  width: calc(100% - 42px); 
  margin: 50px 0; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
}

#empData h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0.3em; 
  font-family: monospace; 
}

#empData img {
  display: block; 
  width: 22em; height: 15em; 
  margin-top: 1em; 
  background-color: #eee; 
}
```

```html
<div id="empData"></div>
```